# Crontab script not saving result in file

Tags: linux, bash, cron, centos-7

I want to backup my database everyday and i have written a script

my.cnf

```
[client]
host=locahost
user=root
password='pw'
```

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/mysqldump --defaults-file=/home/wasifkhalil/my.cnf --set-gtid-purged=OFF testing_dump > /home/wasifkhalil/db_backups/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")_crm_backup.sql
exit
```

now when i run this script

```
[root@instance-main db_backups]# /home/wasifkhalil/script.sh
```

it works perfect and i see the sql file in the folder but when i run it in crontab it doesnt work, what am i doing wrong? (for testing i set it to 16th minute of every hour)

```
16 * * * * root /home/wasifkhalil/script.sh
```

this is the version of Cent OS im on

```
centos-release-7-3.1611.el7.centos.x86_64
```

Comment: You can't run a script by invoking `root`. You need to use the needed shell, in your case `/bin/bash`.

Comment: can u give an example? do u mean run just "16 * * * * /home/wasifkhalil/script.sh" like this?

Comment: To run it as root user, you should place it in root's crontab

Comment: yes im in root's crontab

Comment: 16 * * * * /bin/bash /home/wasifkhalil/script.sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run a bash script as root, you need edit root's crontab like so:
`16 * * * * /bin/bash /path/to/script.sh`

**Explanation:**

```
16 * * * * = At minute 16th of every hour.
/bin/bash = shell interpretor.
/path/to/script.sh = path to the script that you need to schedule.
```